# Email with knex

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, knex.js

I am new to Knex and I tried some transactions. When I send the email address to the users table it sends it like  `{"email":"adriana123@email.com"}` and I am lost, can anybody help me?

```js
app.post('/register', (req, res) =>{
     const {email, name, password } = req.body;
     const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password);
       db.transaction(trx =>{
          trx.insert ({
              has: hash,
              email: email
          })
          .into('login')
          .returning('email')
          .then (loginEmail => {
             return trx('users')
              .returning('*')
              .insert({
                email:loginEmail[0],
                  name: name,
                  joined: new Date()
            }).then(user =>{
                res.json(user[0]);
                        })
        })
        .then(trx.commit)
        .catch(trx.rollback)`
    })
})
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? How does this output differ from the output you're expecting?

Comment: Why would you expect something other than `"email":"adriana123@email.com"`? Note - you've written `has: hash` in the code - did you mean `hash: hash`?

Comment: So the output I need is adriana123@email.com so that in the database is only "adriana123@email.com" not "email":"adriana123@email.com" and I can check for it when the user tries to log in.
The has thing is just a misspelled word in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What has happened is that you are inserting `loginEmail[0]` in the second insert.

What you should be inserting is `loginEmail[0].email`, if not, you are technically inserting an object looking like `{ email: 'adriana123@email.com' }`

```
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
     const { email, name, password } = req.body;
     const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password);
       db.transaction(trx => {
          trx.insert ({
              hash, // make sure you fix this spelling. also, in modern JS it's enough writing like this (no need for email: email)
              email
          })
          .into('login')
          .returning('email')
          .then (dbResponse => {
             return trx('users')
              .returning('*')
              .insert({
                email: dbResponse[0].email,
                  name,
                  joined: new Date(),
            }).then(user => {
                res.json(user[0]);
                        })
        })
        .then(trx.commit)
        .catch(trx.rollback)`
    })
})
```

Took the liberty at adding some formatting and replacing the variable for the dbResponse so it is slightly clearer.